# Get ContentControl Children

Tags: c#, wpf, image, contentcontrol

How can I iterate over the Images in the ContentControls?

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" >

    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource DesignerItemStyle}">
        <Image IsHitTestVisible="True" Source="Media/cross.png"   />
    </ContentControl>

    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource DesignerItemStyle}">
        <Image IsHitTestVisible="True" Source="Media/cross.png"   />
    </ContentControl>

</Canvas>
```

My try does not work:

```
var ccs = canvas.Children;
foreach (ContentControl c in ccs)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(c); i++)
   {
     var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(c, i);
   }
}
```

Comment: The right way to do this would be to change `Canvas` to an `ItemsControl`, with an `ItemsPanel` set to `Canvas`, encapsulate your PNG as view models, and define a template for the view model as the `ContentControl` with `Image`. Then your problem becomes not one of enumerating the `ControlControl.Image` properties, but rather of the view model collection you should have ready access to.

Comment: As far as the question you asked goes, it has [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) written all over it, as well as is missing details about why your try didn't work, and what _specifically_ you weren't able to figure out. Knowing, particularly, why it is you think you need to access the `Image` elements this way, would help others provide an answer to your real question, not the one you posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ:

```
var images = canvas.Children
    .OfType<ContentControl>()
    .Select(cc => cc.Content as Image)
    .Where(img => img != null);
```

As a note, setting `IsHitTestVisible="True"` is redundant. True is the default value.